Some interesting ODEs I am contemplating (just two).
The ODE is as follows:
$$y''+1/y'=y,y(0)=0,y'(0)=1$$
$$y''+1/y=y', y(0)=1,y'(0)=0$$
The first one I multiply by $y'$ to get the following ODE: $y'=\sqrt{y^2-2x}$, don't know how to resolve this ODE though.
The second ODE, again I should do the same trick of multiplying the equation by $y'$ to get:
$\frac{1}{2}(y')^2+\ln(y)=\int^x (y')^2 dx$.
Here I guess I could try iteration, though I am not sure how exactly.
Are these ODEs known before?
Perhaps a good paper with perturbation theory is "cooked" in my mind, time will tell as John from Asia sang...
As @Goncalo pointed out to me (in the comments) the solution for the first ODE should actually satisfy: $y'=\sqrt{y^2-2x+1}$.

Your first solution, at least, needs some attention. According to what's posted at the moment, $y'(0)$ would have to be zero assuming $y(0) = 0$.

@Aruralreader yes, I need to change $y(0)=1$ as well if I am not mistaken. Obviously $y'(0)\ne 0$, since then we would have in the ode a possibility of $1/0$, am I not correct here in assuming that $y'(0)\ne 0$?

Your first solution should be $y'=\sqrt{y^2-2x+1}$ in order to satisfy the initial conditions.

@Gonçalo yes you are correct, forgot to add a constant.

There is actually a known solution for your second ODE. Taking $y'_x=p(y)$ we have
\begin{align}
pp'_y-p=\frac{-1}{y},
\end{align}
the solution to which is given in the 'Handbook of Ordinary Differential Equations Exact Solutions, Methods, and Problems Third Edition' by Polyanin & Zaitsev as
\begin{align}
y=af^{-1}\exp(-\tau^2),\quad p=af^{-1}\exp(-\tau^2)+2a\tau,\\\\
2a^2=1,\quad f=\int\exp(-\tau^2)\mathrm d\tau-C.
\end{align}
You can arrive at this solution by taking $y=1/z(\tau)$, $p=1/z(\tau)+2\tau$, yielding a linear equation. We can find $x(\tau)$ by noting that
\begin{align}
p=y+2a\tau,\quad \tau=\frac{y'_x-y}{2a},\quad \tau'_x=\frac{y''_{xx}-y'_x}{2a}=\frac{1}{2ay},\\\\
x'_\tau=2ay=f^{-1}\exp(-\tau^2),\quad x=\int f^{-1}\exp(-\tau^2)\mathrm d\tau-C_2.
\end{align}
So the parametric solution is
\begin{align}
x(\tau)=\log(f(\tau))-C_2,\quad y(\tau)=\frac{a\exp(-\tau^2)}{f(\tau)},\quad f(\tau)=\int\exp(-\tau^2)\mathrm d\tau-C_1.
\end{align}
We can determine $\tau_0$ using $x(\tau_0)=0$, $y(\tau_0)=0$ and $y'(\tau_0)=1$. After computing each I find the system of 3 equations which $C_1$, $C_2$, and $\tau_0$ must satisfy:
\begin{align}
2\tau_0f(\tau_0)=\exp(-\tau_0^2)\quad C_2=\log(f(\tau_0)),\quad C_1=a\frac{\exp(\tau_0^2)}{f(\tau_0)}.
\end{align}
The first gives the value for $\tau_0$, though in practice could only be solved numerically. Care must also be taken when choosing the positive or negative value for $a$.
